# Difference in opengl es programming for PowerVR and Mali GPU chipsets

Tags: opengl-es, gpu, powervr-sgx, mali

I am developing a framework using OpenGL ES to create 3D applications.
I need to deploy the framework in both PowerVR and Mali GPUs chip-sets.

Is there any aspects to be taken care in programming OpenGL ES for different GPUs (PowerVR and Mali)?

Answer (score 1):

The only significant difference is that the older Mali cores (Mali-300/400 series) only support mediump in the fragment shader, so algorithms relying on highp precision won't work there.

There are surely fine tuning differences, but hard to give a succinct answer to that one. Just focus on writing good clean GL and it should work well everywhere.